# Erro no pyhon, pyautogui

Tags: python, python-2.7

Criei um bot(macro) o qual tem a função de realizar alguns cliques em X tempo.
Fiz o loop para isto.

```
def afkLoop(): #Loop
    pycontrol.broken() #Função
    time.sleep(1800) #Timer
    afkLoop() 

def broken(): #Função
    print "["+(str(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")))+"] Done.."

    pyautogui.click(104,14) #Aba 01
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.press("up")
    pyautogui.press("down")

    time.sleep(3)    
    pyautogui.click(297,17) #Aba 02
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.press("up")
    pyautogui.press("down")

    time.sleep(3)    
    pyautogui.click(475,11) #Aba 03
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.press("up")
    pyautogui.press("down")

    time.sleep(3)    
    pyautogui.click(659,16) #Aba 04
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.press("up")
    pyautogui.press("down")
```

O problema, é que de algumas horas, o programa fecha, consegui captar o erro:
**pyautogui.FailSafeException: PyAutoGUI fail-safe triggered from mouse moving to
upper-left corner. To disable this fail-safe, set pyautogui.FAILSAFE to False.**

Como posso resolver? Estou usando o python 2.7 e a pyautogui.

Comment: "To disable this fail-safe, set pyautogui.FAILSAFE to False."
Onde devo desabilitar isto? como?

Comment: Se souber ler em inglês, tem na [documentação](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#fail-safes)

Comment: Consegui, obrigado :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como um recurso de segurança, um recurso de proteção contra falhas é habilitado por padrão. Quando as funções PyAutoGUI aumentarão, se o cursor do mouse estiver no canto superior esquerdo da tela. Se você perder o controle e precisar parar a atual função PyAutoGUI, continue movendo o cursor do mouse para cima e para a esquerda. Para desativar esse recurso, configure para:

```
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
```

Saiba mais em http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#fail-safes